# googlemock: object of mocked class cannot be created

Tags: c++, googlemock

I got a class Car which uses speedInterface (it has a reference on it).
Now I want to mock speedInterface with Mock_SpeedInterface.

```
class speedInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~speedInterface() {}

    virtual int GetSpeed(void) = 0;
};

class Mock_SpeedInterface : public speedInterface
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetSpeed, int());
};

class Car 
{
public:
    Car(speedInterface& s) : Speedo(s) {}
    virtual ~Car() {}

    speedInterface& Speedo;
    ...

};
TEST(TestCar, Test1) {
    Mock_SpeedInterface mockSpeed;
...
}
```

Trying to create mockSpeed leads to the following compiler error:

> Error  C2259   'Mock_SpeedInterface': cannot instantiate abstract class

IMHO class Mock_SpeedInterface is not an abstract class because it "implements" GetSpeed.
Why do I get this error and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Why did you use `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0` for `GetSpeed` as this method is `non-const`. You should use `MOCK_METHOD0`.

Comment: Oh. You're right. I didn't see it. Changing it to MOCK_METHOD0 fix it. Thank you ver much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetSpeed, int());` is wrong. To have an ordinary answer I will quote the comment of the OP:

> Changing it to MOCK_METHOD0 fix it.